# Php\Javascript web-app on Windows 8.1 issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, windows-8

I have small web-app in PHP with some minor Javascript i wrote on Windows 7 using XAMPP as server which was showing spinner when Ajax was loading.
It worked fine on Win7.

Now when i'm setting same environtment on Windows 8.1 the loading spinner is :

- in case of IE11, always running in left-bottom region of the page.
- in case of other browsers it's firstly hidden but when i run one and only Javascript function it pop up in left-bottom region and stays there same as with IE11.

Anyone could point me what i'm doing wrong and what i'm missing so it would behave normally?

here's code:

1. php page element :

   ```
   <div id="ajaxLoading">Trwa ładowanie, <br/>proszę czekać...</div>
   ```
2. Javascript:

   ```
   jQuery.fn.center = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) /       2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
   this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
   return this;
   }

   $(function() {
   // pokaż spinner w czasie wykonywania żądań AJAX
   $('#ajaxLoading')
   .hide()
   .ajaxStart(function() {
       $(this).center();
       $(this).show();
    })
   .ajaxStop(function() {
       $(this).hide();
   })
    ;
   });


     function usunpoz(idnadstan, link)
    {

    var odp = confirm("Czy na pewno chcesz usunąć tą pozycję?");

       if(odp) {
     $.post(
     "nadstan.usun.php",
           { id : idnadstan},
            function(response) {
           if(response == 'ok') {
       $(link).parent().parent().find('td').css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
       $(link).parent().html("");
       location.reload();          

   } else {
       alert('Wystąpił błąd przy przetwarzaniu zapytania. Prosimy spróbować ponownie.');
   }
   }
   );
    }

    }
   ```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently problem was that on Win 8.1 machine the default protocol was https and in whole php there was one script from on-line resource with absolute url reffered to http protocol.

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
```

so i just downloaded it compressed version and changed the access path to protocol-relative paths like

```
src="js/jquery.min.js"
```